# JSTL forEach not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat, jstl

I have a JSP with some JSTL tags, all of them work fine but forEach. This is my JSP Code:

**header.jsp**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec"
        uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <div>
       <!-- header stuff -->
    </div>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <%@include file="header.jsp"%>
    <c:if test='${pageContext["request"].userPrincipal.principal.enabled eq false}'>
          <div class='alert alert-warn fade in'>
          ....
      </div>
    </c:if>

    <table>
         <c:choose>
               <c:when test="${not empty results}">
                   <c:forEach var="item" items="${results}">
                     ...
                   </c:forEach>
               </c:when>
               <c:otherwise>
                  <tr id="noItems" class="accordion-toggle" >
                      <td>No items.</td>
                  </tr>
               </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
    </table>

</html>
```

I can't see anything, nor results, nor "No items" message.

My dependencies below:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
```

Deployed on tomcat 6 it doesn't work, but if I deploy it on Eclipse using Maven Tomcat plugin, it works fine. 
Does anyone know where could be the error?

EDIT:

I'm getting this error in console:

> [TagLibraryInfoImpl] Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute

Comment: Tomcat doesn't provide JSTL out the box, yet you've told Maven that this is the case. In other words, you've manually installed it in some way and that part was likely done wrongly given the symptoms (e.g. API/impl mismatch or duplication; the error message hints that you're actually using JSTL 1.1 impl with JSTL 1.2 API). If you tell more about how exactly you installed JSTL, then we can point out the mistake. In the meanwhile, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: @BalusC I edited the post to show the current versions. The only thing I did is to add those dependencies to pom.xml. Tomcat is totally brand new. I'm also using Spring MVC 3.2.1.RELEASE, is it possible that it includes JSTL 1.1 anywhere?

Comment: No idea. Extract the Maven-built WAR file and check the JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @BalusC I checked it but there's no JSTL1.1 jar, only jstl1.2.jar

Comment: JSTL 1.1 impl has the (rather confusing) filename `standard.jar`. Did you also look specifically for this?

Comment: I had standard 1.1.2 dependency but I removed it in an attempt to solve this problem. I have no longer that jar in my project.

Comment: And you're still getting the error *"[TagLibraryInfoImpl] Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute"*? Apparently your build is still dirty. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: Already did, and I'm still getting the same error. I'm gonna look for any dependency in spring mvc jars... What annoys me is, why is c:if working fine and c:forEach crashes?

Comment: Because there's a JSTL 1.1 impl in the runtime classpath, as indicated by the error. The internals of `<c:forEach>` has changed in JSTL 1.2. You're going to have to wade through all paths covered by the webapp's runtime classpath. This includes server's own libraries, the JRE's own libraries, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Eclipse "Open Type" dialog I came up with two forEach implementations. One in `jasper-compiler.jar`, auto imported from hbase dependency, and the other one in `velocity.jar`. 
They were in conflict with my current `jstl1-2.jar` implementation of forEach.

Excluding these jars from my dependencies the problem is gone.